# Remove nodes with 0 edges before drawing the graph (dot, graphviz)

Tags: graphviz, dot

How can I remove nodes without edges from my graph before plotting with `dot -Tpng mcve.gv -o mcve.png`?

**Current Result:**
[image]
**Wanted Result:**
[image]

Reading the documentation and searching the web I found the following [answer](http://www.graphviz.org/content/hiding-node-have-no-arrows-connected) which seems fine at first glance. (remove all nodes with 0 edges)

```
vpr -c 'N[$.degree==0]{delete($);}' mvce.gv | dot ...
```

Unfortionately this command gives the following error:

```
gvpr: "<command line>", line 2: delete($)<<< 
 -- cannot convert node_t to graph_t
```

Which seems weird as from what I read `N[predicate]{action}` should only execute `action` on nodes.

A minimal example of my graph:

```
graph main_graph {
  node1;
  node2;
  node3;
  node4; // not used

  subgraph graph1 {
    edge [color=red,penwidth=2]
    node1 -- node2;
  }

  subgraph graph2 {
    edge [color="blue",penwidth=2]
    node2 -- node3;
    node1 -- node3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gvpr doc](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) indicates that `delete` actually has 2 arguments - first the graph to delete from, then the object to delete.

You are only passing a node, that seems to explain the convert error.

Since there is no reference to the graph available, passing either `NULL` or `root` (see the same doc) can be passed as a argument:

```
gvpr -c "N[$.degree==0]{delete(root, $)}" mygraph.gv
gvpr -c "N[$.degree==0]{delete(NULL, $)}" mygraph.gv
```

will result int

```
graph main_graph {
    subgraph graph1 {
        edge [color=red,
            penwidth=2
        ];
        node1 -- node2       [color=red,
            penwidth=2];
    }
    subgraph graph2 {
        edge [color=blue,
            penwidth=2
        ];
        node1 -- node3       [color=blue,
            penwidth=2];
        node2 -- node3       [color=blue,
            penwidth=2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I must have missed that skimming the documentation.

Comment: I didn't understand, is there no tool that removes nodes without edges built in?