# How to drop nodes with graphviz / gvpr

Tags: graphviz

How can I use gvpr to drop all nodes except those with outdegree=="0" and their parent nodes?

So given

```
A > B
B > C
B > D
D > E
```

drop A only.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what `outdegree=="0"` is, but: [Remove nodes with 0 edges before drawing the graph (dot, graphviz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965713/remove-nodes-with-0-edges-before-drawing-the-graph-dot-graphviz) ??

Answer (score 2):

create an array of all nodes to be deleted (or not).
Do not delete if
outdegree==0
or
if tail of edge where head.outdegree==0

```
BEGIN{
  int DELETE[];
}
BEG_G{
  $tvtype=TV_ne   // nodes first
}
N{
  if ($.outdegree==0){
    print ("// DELETE: ", $.name);
    DELETE[$]=0;
  }else{
    DELETE[$]=1;
  }
}
E{
  print ("// head: ", $.head);
  if (DELETE[$.head]==0){ 
    print ("// DELETE: ", $.name);
    DELETE[$.tail]=0;
  }
}
END_G{
  node_t aNode;
  for (DELETE[aNode]){
    if (DELETE[aNode]==1){
      delete($G, aNode);
    }
  }
}
```